# PySpark lead based on condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, conditional-statements, lead

I have a dataset such as:

```
Condition | Date
0 | 2019/01/10
1 | 2019/01/11
0 | 2019/01/15
1 | 2019/01/16
1 | 2019/01/19
0 | 2019/01/23
0 | 2019/01/25
1 | 2019/01/29
1 | 2019/01/30
```

I would like to get the next value of the date column when condition == 1 was met.

The desired output would be something like:

```
Condition | Date | Lead
0 | 2019/01/10 | 2019/01/15
1 | 2019/01/11 | 2019/01/16
0 | 2019/01/15 | 2019/01/23
1 | 2019/01/16 | 2019/01/19
1 | 2019/01/19 | 2019/01/29
0 | 2019/01/23 | 2019/01/25
0 | 2019/01/25 | NaN
1 | 2019/01/29 | 2019/01/30
1 | 2019/01/30 | NaN
```

How can I perform that?

Please keep in mind it's a very large dataset - which I will have to partition and group by an UUID so the solution has to be somewhat performant.

Comment: why is the lead "2019/01/15" for the first record? shouldn't it be 2019/01/11?

Comment: also, why is there "2019/01/23" in lead when it's condition is 0? wouldn't that be 2019/01/16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the *next value of the date column when condition == 1 was met*, we can use the `first` window function with a `when().otherwise()` which emulates the `lead`.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('dt_w_cond1_lead', 
               func.first(func.when(func.col('cond') == 1, func.col('dt')), ignorenulls=True).
               over(wd.partitionBy().orderBy('dt').rowsBetween(1, sys.maxsize))
               ). \
    show()

# +----+----------+---------------+
# |cond|        dt|dt_w_cond1_lead|
# +----+----------+---------------+
# |   0|2019-01-10|     2019-01-11|
# |   1|2019-01-11|     2019-01-16|
# |   0|2019-01-15|     2019-01-16|
# |   1|2019-01-16|     2019-01-19|
# |   1|2019-01-19|     2019-01-29|
# |   0|2019-01-23|     2019-01-29|
# |   0|2019-01-25|     2019-01-29|
# |   1|2019-01-29|     2019-01-30|
# |   1|2019-01-30|           null|
# +----+----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function [`lead`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lead.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lead). As you said in the question, for more performance, you will need to have more partitions.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, '2019/01/10'),
     (1, '2019/01/11'),
     (0, '2019/01/15'),
     (1, '2019/01/16'),
     (1, '2019/01/19'),
     (0, '2019/01/23'),
     (0, '2019/01/25'),
     (1, '2019/01/29'),
     (1, '2019/01/30')],
    ['Condition', 'Date'])
```

Script:

```py
w = W.partitionBy('Condition').orderBy('Date')
df = df.withColumn('Lead', F.lead('Date').over(w))

df.show()
# +---------+----------+----------+
# |Condition|      Date|      Lead|
# +---------+----------+----------+
# |        0|2019/01/10|2019/01/15|
# |        0|2019/01/15|2019/01/23|
# |        0|2019/01/23|2019/01/25|
# |        0|2019/01/25|      null|
# |        1|2019/01/11|2019/01/16|
# |        1|2019/01/16|2019/01/19|
# |        1|2019/01/19|2019/01/29|
# |        1|2019/01/29|2019/01/30|
# |        1|2019/01/30|      null|
# +---------+----------+----------+
```